# OpenCV identical images return different results

Tags: python, image, opencv

I'm trying to analyze a set of images in a directory but only one image works. All images are roughly the same size (3MB) and come from the same original image. All are viewable in GIMP and Photos, but cv2.imshow only works with slice_0_15.jpg
What is happening here?
Using Python version 3.8.3, OpenCV version 4.2.0

```
for file in os.listdir("scanned_extrudate"): #go through all 18 slices in the directory
    print("Analyzing file " + str(file))
    image = cv2.imread(file)

    if image is None:
        print("Error: no image selected")

    else:
        rows,cols,_ = image.shape #dimensions of image (eg 200x300)
        print("Image: " + str(rows) + " rows, " + str(cols) + " columns")
```

Output:

```
Analyzing file slice_0_0.jpg
Error: no image selected
Analyzing file slice_0_1.jpg
Error: no image selected
Analyzing file slice_0_10.jpg
Error: no image selected
Analyzing file slice_0_11.jpg
Error: no image selected
Analyzing file slice_0_12.jpg
Error: no image selected
Analyzing file slice_0_13.jpg
Error: no image selected
Analyzing file slice_0_14.jpg
Error: no image selected
Analyzing file slice_0_15.jpg
Image: 19935 rows, 928 columns
Analyzing file slice_0_16.jpg
Error: no image selected
Analyzing file slice_0_17.jpg
Error: no image selected
Analyzing file slice_0_2.jpg
Error: no image selected
Analyzing file slice_0_3.jpg
Error: no image selected
Analyzing file slice_0_4.jpg
Error: no image selected
Analyzing file slice_0_5.jpg
Error: no image selected
Analyzing file slice_0_6.jpg
Error: no image selected
Analyzing file slice_0_7.jpg
Error: no image selected
Analyzing file slice_0_8.jpg
Error: no image selected
Analyzing file slice_0_9.jpg
Error: no image selected
```

When I type 'file *' in the terminal, I get the same result for all the images: (only difference is the dimensions)

```
slice_0_0.jpg:  JPEG image data, JFIF standard 1.01, resolution (DPI), density 2400x2400, segment length 16, Exif Standard: [TIFF image data, little-endian, direntries=7, xresolution=98, yresolution=106, resolutionunit=2, software=GIMP 2.10.14, datetime=2020:07:10 13:34:33], progressive, precision 8, 1088x19935, frames 1
```

Comment: How were the images generated? Was anything at all done to the rest that wasn't done to `slice_0_15.jpg`, or vice versa? Can you regenerate the images? How does your code work with just random JPGs?

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are not reading images inside of the *scanned_extrudate* file. You are seeing images cos of looking right directory but you are trying to read in wrong directory. This should fix your problem:

```
image = cv2.imread("/ur/directory/to/scanned_extrudate/" + file)
```

Comment: You're right that I was trying to read from the wrong directory, but this code didn't work for me. @lenik 's os.path.join(FOLDER,file) ended up working

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import os

FOLDER = "scanned_extrudate"

for file in os.listdir(FOLDER): #go through all 18 slices in the directory
    print("Analyzing file " + str(file))
    image = cv2.imread(os.path.join( FOLDER, file))
```